# Observable - Listen to EventEmitter & emit initial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rxjs, angular-material2

I am currently trying to implement a table from the [Angular Material Library](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples).

I need to include pagination & sorting, so I followed the provided example **"Table with sorting"** & **"Table with pagination"**.

The difference I have is that get my data from a REST endpoint using the `HttpClient` that Angular provides.

---

This is the current code (simplified):

**Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getData(page: number, size: number, sort: string): Observable<Data[]> {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('page', String(page))
      .set('size', String(size))
      .set('sort', String(sort));
    return this.http.get<Data[]>('/api/v1/data', {params: params});
  }
}
```

**DataSource:**

```
export class DataDataSource extends DataSource<Data> {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private sort: MdSort, private paginator: MdPaginator) {
    super();
  }

  connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Data[]> {
    const displayDataChanges = [
      this.sort.mdSortChange,
      this.paginator.page
    ];

    return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).flatMap(() => {
      let sortStr = this.sort.active + (this.sort.direction == 'asc' ? ',asc' : ',desc');
      return this.dataService.getData(this.paginator.pageIndex, this.paginator.pageSize, sortStr);
    });
  }

  disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
  }
}
```

---

**Actual Question**

In the example a `Behaviour` is used to emit an `Event` to the `Observable` everytime the data changes.
As I am using a REST Endpoint I do not have this behaviour.

By consequence, the displayed table **is empty until a pagination or sort event is emitted**.

How do I intially trigger the subscriber (the table) to initially load the data?

---

*I am very new to JavaScript & Rx, so I already apologize in advance if this is a stupid question :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself.

---

The problem was not that the `Observable` was cold, as the table actually already subscribed to the `Observable` after the call to `connect()`.

---

The problem was that the returned `Observable`did of course not emit any events until a sort or pagination happened (due to the `merge()`).

---

The solution was to add a trigger that can be called to refresh the data:

```
export class DataDataSource extends DataSource<Data> {

  private dataChange: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private sort: MdSort, private paginator: MdPaginator) {
    super();
  }

  public refreshData(): void {
    this.dataChange.next(null);
  }

  connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Data[]> {
    const displayDataChanges = [
      this.sort.mdSortChange,
      this.paginator.page,
      this.dataChange
    ];

    return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).flatMap(() => {
      let sortStr = this.sort.active + (this.sort.direction == 'asc' ? ',asc' : ',desc');
      return this.dataService.getData(this.paginator.pageIndex, this.paginator.pageSize, sortStr);
    });
  }

  disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Observable you have created is currently cold as it is not being subscribed to. You should be able to subscribe to the observable by doing the following.

```
    Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).flatMap(() => {
      let sortStr = this.sort.active + (this.sort.direction == 'asc' ? ',asc' : ',desc');
      return this.dataService.getData(this.paginator.pageIndex, this.paginator.pageSize, sortStr);
    }).subscribe(
      (result) => //do something,
      (err) => //do something
    );
```

When initiating and subscribing to an observable in a component it is important to remember to unsubscribe from the Observable after the component is destroyed otherwise it will remain hot. To do this set the Subscription to a method:

```
   subscription: Subsction;
   connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Data[]> {
     const displayDataChanges = [
       this.sort.mdSortChange,
       this.paginator.page
     ];

    this.subscription = Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).flatMap(() => {
      let sortStr = this.sort.active + (this.sort.direction == 'asc' ? ',asc' : ',desc');
      return this.dataService.getData(this.paginator.pageIndex, this.paginator.pageSize, sortStr);
    });
   }

   ngOnDestroy() {
     this.subscription.unsubscribe();
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately that was not the problem. See my answer.